# How to create a fixed and detached menu in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good morning everyone,

I am working on a menu and would like it to behave a certain way.

When I scroll down, the "TOP" section moves up (this is already working)

I would like the "MY MENU" section to be hidden initially and only appear when   the "TOP" section disappears up when scroll.

and example of what I am trying to achieve can be seen at https://flipkart.com? (on mobile vue)

here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gad123/j695to5b/1/ (solved)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="span">
<div class="wll">
<h3>TOP</h3>
</div>

</div>

</div> 
</div>
<div id="nav-wrapper">

<div id="na">
<div id="nav" class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
<div class="span12"  style="background:#888;
padding:1em 0 1em 0;">

<span class="navbar-text">
My menu
</span>
</div>
</div> 
div> 
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="span3">
<h2>some lorem ipsum for scrolling:</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam 
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed 
diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet 
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet.
<div id="detach"><b>test</b></div>

</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());
$('#nav').affix({
offset: $('#nav').position()
});
$('#nav').detached({
offset: $('#detach').position()
});
```

css:

```
#nav.affix {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%

}

h3{color:red;}
.top{
background:#999; 
width: 100%
}

#nav.detached {
position:static;
top:0;
}


#nav > .navbar-inner {
border-left: 0;
border-right: 0;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
-o-border-radius: 0;    
}

h3{
color:orange
}

.wll{
padding:1em 0 1em 0;
background:#444;
}
```

Comment: So far you have told us what you're trying to build but you have not told us what your problem is.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the fiddle?
My problem is that I am unable to hide the  "My Menu" section and only display it when the "TOP" section has completely gone off the screen

Comment: I am pretty sure using position:sticky will make it more simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#nav-wrapper').height($("#nav").height());

if($(".top").height()> $(document).scrollTop()){
    $("#nav").css({"display": "none"});
}

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(".top").height()< $(document).scrollTop()){
        $("#nav").css({"display": "block"});
    }
    else{
        $("#nav").css({"display": "none"});
    }
});

$('#nav').affix({
    offset: $('#nav').position()
});

$('#nav').detached({
    offset: $('#detach').position()
});
```

You can compare the actual scroll height with the height of '.top'

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and easiest way to go about it. i tested it on your fiddle.
Alright so i made some changes to your code and it worked perfectly

change the id="na" to id="menu" as shown below

```
<div id="menu">
<div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div  class="span12"  style="background:#888;
            padding:1em 0 1em 0;">

                <span class="navbar-text">
                My menu
                </span>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </div> <!-- navbar-inner -->
</div> <!-- navbar -->
```

add the following to your css

```
#menu {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
width:100%; 
background-color:#DDDDDD;
color: #FFFFFF;
z-index:9999;
display: none;
```

}

and change your script to

```
$(document).ready(function(){                    
    $(window).scroll(function(){                          
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $('#menu').fadeIn(500);
        } else {
            $('#menu').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
});
```

link to the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7wfryfmL/3/

Comment: could you share the fiddle please

Comment: thanks bro. 
i made some changes and this is a nicer one.
https://jsfiddle.net/gad123/j695to5b/1/